# ChartJS type changing doesn't work correctly from pie type

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js

I want to build a chart that can adapt when the data changes. I also want to be able to change its type: line, bar, or pie.

I have already made some progress, but I am encountering several errors.
First, I encounter an error when I want to update my graph with a slightly different data structure (data3 on JSFiddle).

Error:

> "133:44 Uncaught TypeError:
> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'values')"

Also, my biggest problem is that after changing my chart to "pie" mode, if I change to "line" or "bar", then the chart becomes completely wrong and the shape changes no longer make sense. I just want return on line/bar mode in the way to be as same as the graph was on these mode. I need help on this level.

For pie mode, I use the sum of values for each time period:

```
if (newType === "pie") {
temp.data.labels = temp.data.datasets.map(function(dataset) {
  return dataset.label;
});

temp.data.datasets = [{
  backgroundColor: temp.data.datasets.map(function(dataset) {
    return dataset.backgroundColor;
  }),
  data: temp.data.datasets.map(function(dataset) {
    return dataset.data.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  })
}];
}
```

You can see and try it here:

[My JSFiddle : Flexible data chart](https://jsfiddle.net/Lino16/582rsLj4/70/)

Comment: I think you just complicated a bit the analysis, trying to cover all cases. I'd recommend to simplify, with the risk of being slightly inefficient, by separating the data from the configuration, and most importantly, ignoring the previous state of the chart and always synthesizing the next chart configuration from the initial unchanging objects. I don't get the full scope of your functions, but you may get inspiration from [this fork of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/28oyu5xk/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
var data0 = {
    axis: ["June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
    values: [
        { id: 1, values: [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] },
        { id: 2, values: [1, 2, 4, 8, 3, 2, 4] },
        { id: 3, values: [1, 2, 4, 9, 3, 2, 9] }
    ]
}

var data1 = {
    axis: ["June", "July", "August"],
    values: [
        { id: 1, values: [2, 1, 3] },
        { id: 2, values: [4, 5, 6] },
        { id: 3, values: [8, 9, 7] }
    ]
};

var data2 = {
    axis: ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"],
    values: [
        { id: 1, values: [10, 12, 11, 10] },
        { id: 2, values: [13, 9, 10, 10] },
        { id: 3, values: [8, 9, 7, 10] }
    ]
};

var data3 = {
    axis: ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday2"],
    values: [{ id: 0, values: [10, 12, 11, 10] }]
};

var config = {
    data: {
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "company1",
                fill: false,
                borderColor: "purple",
                backgroundColor: "purple"
            },
            {
                label: "company2",
                fill: false,
                borderColor: "green",
                backgroundColor: "green"
            },
            {
                label: "company3",
                fill: false,
                borderColor: "red",
                backgroundColor: "red"
            }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true
    }
};

var myChart;
var currentDataIndex = 0;
var dataArr = [data0, data1, data2, data3];
var type = '';

$("#line").click(function() {
    type = 'line';
    mixDataConfig();
});

$("#bar").click(function() {
    type = 'bar';
    mixDataConfig();
});

$("#pie").click(function() {
    type = 'pie';
    mixDataConfig();
});

$("#switch").click(function() {
    currentDataIndex = (currentDataIndex + 1) % dataArr.length; // Increment index and wrap a
    mixDataConfig();
});

function mixDataConfig() {
    var currentData = dataArr[currentDataIndex];
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

    // Remove the old chart and all its event handlers
    if (myChart) {
        myChart.destroy();
    }

    // Create a deep copy of the config object
    var temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(config));
    temp.type = type;
    var nDatasets = currentData.values.length,
        configDatasets = temp.data.datasets.slice(0, nDatasets);
        // datasets from config object

    if(type === "line"){
        temp.data = {
            labels: currentData.axis,
            datasets: configDatasets.map(
                function(dataset, index){
                    return {
                        ...dataset,
                        //fill: true, // just testing
                        data: currentData.values[index].values
                    };
                }
            )
        }
    }
    else if(type === "bar"){
        temp.data = {
            labels: currentData.axis,
            datasets: configDatasets.map(
                function(dataset, index){
                    return {
                        ...dataset,
                        data: currentData.values[index].values
                    };
                }
            )
        }
    }
    else/* if(type === "pie")*/{
        temp.data.labels = configDatasets.map(({label}) => label);
        temp.data.datasets = [{
            backgroundColor: configDatasets.map(function(dataset) {
                return dataset.backgroundColor;
            }),
            data: currentData.values.map(function(value) {
                return value.values.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
            })
        }];
    }

    myChart = new Chart(ctx, temp);
}
```